# Version compatibility issue for dependency @angular-devkit/build-angular in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

I have created an new angular project and npm install is working fine but I am getting below error during build:

```
C:\Users\212807091\Documents\GIT_Codebase\idm-gui\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allErrors')
    at module.exports (C:\Users\212807091\Documents\GIT_Codebase\idm-gui\node_modules\ajv-errors\index.js:4:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\212807091\Documents\GIT_Codebase\idm-gui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\212807091\Documents\GIT_Codebase\idm-gui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\schema-utils\src\index.js:7:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

Please find below contents of package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-oauth-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^2.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.0-next.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

And version of the node and npm in cmd:
nodejs: v16.16.0
npm: 8.11.0
ng: 15.1.1

I tried changing the version for dependency "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.0-next.0", to older one, but older version is not compatible with current version of angular.

Could you guys please help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you find the current version of each of the packages that are causing the problem and then replace whatever version you have in your package.json

When you're done modifying the package.json, delete the package.json-lock and use the npm install command to make sure the changes take effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).